# Proof that $A=\{a_1,..,a_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to follow the solution for $A=${$a_1,..,a_n$} $\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact and the solution is a bit unclear. I'm assuming the green underline should be read as $i=1,...n$ ?

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed, that should be read as an "i". (any other questions about it?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be $i\in \{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. Technically, the statement:

> $a_i\in \bigcup_{j\in J} A_j$

does not contain an "unbound" variable $j$, so it wouldn't even make sense to state:

> ... for $j\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

I would prefer to prove this theorem by induction on $n$, showing:

1. If $a\in A$ then $\{a\}$ is compact.
2. If $A_1,A_2\subseteq A$ are compact, then $A_1\cup A_2$ is compact.

The first is trivial, the second is quite useful in its own right and is easily proved since, given any cover:

$$A_1\cup A_2 \subseteq \bigcup_{j\in J} U_j$$

Then $\{U_j\}$ covers $A_1$ and $A_2$, so, for $i=1,2$, since $A_i$ are compact, there are finite $J_i\subseteq J$ so that:

$$A_i\subseteq \bigcup_{j\in J_i} U_j$$

Then:

$$A_1\cup A_2 \subseteq \bigcup_{j\in J_1\cup\, J_2} U_j$$

and $J_1\cup J_2$ is finite since $J_1,J_2$ are finite.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any open cover of A then each element will belong to a open set and there are finitely many elements so the subcocer will be finite so we are done